# Facebook Customer Chat Plugin not working

Tags: facebook, sdk, facebook-chat

The chat plugin does not work, installed everything correctly on the site, but the chat does not appear on the site. I checked the console - there is a connection to SDK, what could be the problem?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  page_id="184854859536XXXX">
</div>
```

Comment: You’ve gone over the Troubleshooting Tips in the plugin documentation already?

Comment: @misorude Yes, I checked the hint. My site [link](https://omelyanenko.pro/)

Comment: `<div id="fb-root"></div>` should go into the body of the document, not the head.

Comment: just did it, nothing happened

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem Sasha?

Comment: @Brian Duncan 

It was necessary to add function initialization before connecting the SDK

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml      : true,    
      version    : 'v3.0'
    });
  };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'facebook-developer-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
  };
(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="YOUR ID"
  logged_in_greeting="Hello. How we can help you?"
  logged_out_greeting="Hello. How we can help you?">
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this, created an app and used its ID. Used rest of your code but no luck.

Comment: you have to whitelist the domain or have it be public. tipically a dev server domain must be added. like myapp.test.
also check any addblocker or even firefox own blocker. facebook is instantly blocked by most of them.